# Failed to open stream in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have just installed new laravel version with the command

```
laravel new updated
```

After installation when I have run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

I got following error[image: see the image for error]

Comment: Run `composer install` from your project root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto your project root directory and type this command: `composer install`

It will automatically install all dependency in `vendor/` directory.

Hope this will be fixed your issue!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's cached in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Try: `php artisan config:clear`.